# compare multidimsensional array values

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

**I have an array:**

```
    array (
     [0] => Array (
         [host] => google.nl
         [class] => IN
         [ttl] => 279310
         [type] => NS
         [target] => ns3.google.com)
     [1] => Array (
         [host] => google.nl
         [class] => IN
         [ttl] => 279310
         [type] => NS
         [target] => ns4.google.com)
     [2] => Array (
         [host] => google.nl
         [class] => IN
         [ttl] => 279310
         [type] => NS
         [target] => ns2.google.com)
```

this array is made ​​with the `dns_get_record ()` function. This is a different amount of variables per domain.
how can I compare `[0]['target']` with`[1]['target']` and `[2]['target']` and if there are more with the rest of the targets?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language is this code written in, this is an example for a solution to this problem in C# \ Java, of course there are many other ways.

use a simple for loop, meaning: if the big array's name is "mainArray", you'll need to do:

```
foreach (int i=0;i<mainArray.length();i++)
{
  if !(mainArray[i]["target"].Equals(mainArray[i+1]["target"]))
       return false;
}
return true;
```